# Update database with visual studio database projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-schema

Hy,

I'am trying to use Visual Studio 2012 database project to upgrade a database to a newer version but i'am having a weird problem.I select the source database then the target database and hit compare.Visual Studio generates the script with the differences and when i execute it fails because it tries to drop tables without first dropping the FK constraints that are on those tables.(normally it should first script all the constrains from a table,drop them,drop the table,after that create the new table and finally recreating the constraints)

Do you have any ideas why it tries to do directly drop table without dropping constraints first.
Am i missing some settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug to me. Try posting the same question on the [SSDT forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/home?forum=ssdt).

If you have access to a copy of [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), it might be worth trying the same comparison to see if this works better. If you're using a database project as a data source, you'll need to select "source control", then "scripts folder", and browse to the folder that contains the .sqlproj file. Here at Red Gate we're working on improving database project support in SQL Compare so we'd welcome any feedback or questions.

Answer (score 1):

If the tables that are being dropped in your database are not in your schema definition and you have got the "DROP objects in target but not in project" option selected in the Deployment Options, then it will try to drop them.

Have you checked this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i work with database generating code from data models, or scrips, i often get that problem, so i have an script just for deleting those keys, sometimes i have to drop my database manually rather than executing the query, because most of the times it does but not completely, so i first dro the database, generate the script and run the script just for erasing the keys